# Implementing a copyWith function on a struct

Tags: rust

I want to be able to create copies of an object but specify a new field, so that the copy has everything the same except for the new field.

Code that works would be something like:

```
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
    address: String,
}

impl Person {
    fn new(name: String, age: u32, address: String) -> Self {
        Self { name, age, address }
    }

    fn copy_with(&self, name: Option<String>, age: Option<u32>, address: Option<String>) -> Self {
        Self {
            name: name.unwrap_or_else(|| self.name.clone()),
            age: age.unwrap_or(self.age),
            address: address.unwrap_or_else(|| self.address.clone()),
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem like idiomatic rust. I believe there's a copy or clone trait I can implement, but will it do what I need (allow me to specify a new field instead of just giving me an exact copy of the original). Or is there a popular crate or something?

Comment: How about making the fields public? There's minimal encapsulation with this API as is, so might as well. Then the caller can have full control over the cloning by writing, e.g., `Person { age: 42, ..orig }`.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to add a method for each field that does what you want. For instance, to clone a `Person` and give it a new `name`:

```rust
impl Person {
    fn with_name(&self, name: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            // use the new name
            name,

            // take the remaining field values from `self`
            ..self.clone()
        }
    }
}
```

This takes advantage of the [functional update syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/struct-expr.html#functional-update-syntax), where some fields are written explicitly and the rest of the fields take on the value after the `..`, in this case `self.clone()`.

For prior art, the standard library has similar methods for `std::path::Path`. Here's [`Path::with_extension()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.with_extension):

> ```
> pub fn with_extension<S: AsRef<OsStr>>(&self, extension: S) -> PathBuf
> ```
>
> Creates an owned PathBuf like self but with the given extension.

So I would say this fits the bill for idiomatic Rust.

Comment: I want a way to overwrite one or more fields in the new copy. Not just a specific field, apologies if the question was not clear. E.g. I might want to do copyWith(name: "My new name") or copyWith(name: "New name", age: 21).

Comment: This pattern allows you to chain the calls together, if that's satisfactory: `person.with_name("New name").with_age(21)`